# I don't understand why aren't my Entry Widgets not accepting any input

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, tkinter-entry, ttkbootstrap

I tried doing everything but *my Entry boxes aren't ready to accept any input*

First just install ttkbootstrap to execute the code.

```
pip install ttkbootstrap
```

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as mgb
from ttkbootstrap import *
import sqlite3 as sql

conn = sql.connect("Stock Data.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

def AddData(Date, Quality, Quantity, Invoice, Supplier):
    cursor.execute(f'''INSERT INTO Stock (Date, Quality, Quantity, Invoice, Supplier) VALUES ('{Date}','{Quality}',{Quantity},{Invoice},'{Supplier}'));''')
def SortData():
    pass
def ResetAdd():
    Date.set("Date")
    Quality.set("Quality")
    Quantity.set("Quantity")
    Invoice.set("Invoice Number")
    Supplier.set("Supplier")
def ResetSort():
    pass

frame = Window("Stock Book", themename="superhero")

if mgb.askquestion("First Time", "Is this app opened for the FIRST TIME?") == "yes":
    cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Stock')
    cursor.execute(''' CREATE TABLE Stock
            (Date TEXT,
            Quality TEXT,
            Quantity INT,
            Invoice INT,
            Supplier TEXT);''')

root = Frame(frame, padding=10)
root.pack(pady=5, fill=X, side=TOP)

nb = Notebook(root)
nb.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(10, 0), expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

AddDataFrame = Frame(nb, padding=15)
AddDataFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=(10, 5), expand=YES)
Date = StringVar(AddDataFrame)  
DatEntry = Entry(AddDataFrame, width=50, textvariable=Date) #Date
DatEntry.pack(fill=X, pady=5)
Quality = StringVar(AddDataFrame)
QualityEntry = Entry(AddDataFrame, textvariable=Quality) #Quality
QualityEntry.pack(fill=X, pady=5)
Quantity = StringVar(AddDataFrame)
QuantityEntry = Entry(AddDataFrame, textvariable=Quantity) #Quantity
QuantityEntry.pack(fill=X, pady=5)
Invoice = StringVar(AddDataFrame)
InvoiceNumberEntry = Entry(AddDataFrame, textvariable=Invoice) #Invoice SupplierNumber
InvoiceNumberEntry.pack(fill=X, pady=5)
Supplier = StringVar(AddDataFrame)
SupplierEntry = Entry(AddDataFrame, textvariable=Supplier) #Supplier
SupplierEntry.pack(fill=X, pady=5)
ResetButton = Button(AddDataFrame, text="RESET", style="Danger.TButton", width=22, command=ResetAdd) #Reset
ResetButton.pack(pady=10, side = LEFT)
SaveButton = Button(AddDataFrame, text="ADD DATA", style="Success.TButton", width=22, command=lambda:AddData(
    Date.get(),
    Quality.get(),
    Quantity.get(),
    Invoice.get(),
    Supplier.get()
)) #Save
SaveButton.pack(pady=10, side = RIGHT)

SortDataFrame = Frame(nb, padding=15)
SortDataFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, pady=(10, 5), expand=YES)
SorterEntry = Entry(SortDataFrame, width=50) #Sorter
SorterEntry.pack(fill=X, pady=5)
SorterEntry.insert(END, "Sorter")
SortererEntry = Entry(SortDataFrame) #Quality
SortererEntry.pack(fill=X, pady=5)
SortererEntry.insert(END, "Value")
ResetButton = Button(SortDataFrame, text="RESET", style="Danger.TButton", width=22, command=ResetSort) #Reset
ResetButton.pack(pady=10, side = LEFT)
SortButton = Button(SortDataFrame, text="SORT", style="Success.TButton", width=22, command=SortData) #Sort
SortButton.pack(pady=10, side = RIGHT)

nb.add(AddDataFrame, text="Add Data", sticky=NW)
nb.add(SortDataFrame, text="Sort Data", sticky=NW)

tk.mainloop()
```

I tried reading the docs, changing the code, re-running the code a 100 times, restarting my laptop, everything, but it wont accept any input.

Comment: When I run this code I get a syntax error when trying to execute a sql statement. I strongly encourage you to do a couple of things. First, use [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). It will make your code much easier to read for others. For example, only capitalize the name of classes, not variables. Second, make the buttons call functions rather than using lambda (eg: `command=do_save`).  It's much, much easier to debug than trying to debug a lambda.

Comment: There is extra `)` at the end of INSERT statement. Also it is better to use placeholders in SQL statement to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Your entry widgets seem to accept data when I run it. I don't think it's a problem with getting data, it's a problem with your sql statement.

Comment: It seems like calling `askquestion()` during setting up main/root window messes up `tkinter`.  Try calling `askquestion()` before creating the main/root window.  Also you need to call `conn.commit()` after inserting data into database table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Adding `trace_add` worked for me.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def my_callback(var, index, mode):
    print(name.get())


name = tk.StringVar()
name.set("default name")
name.trace_add('write', my_callback)

entry_field = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=name)
entry_field.pack()

root.mainloop()
```